# Coloring webkit-scrollbar-track on hover

Tags: html, css

I've got some CSS which highlights webkit's scrollbar track and thumb. It looks like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 12px; height: 12px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background: white; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { background: #ddd; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { background: #999; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover { background: blue; }

.scroller
{
    overflow: auto;
    font: 16px/1.5 Arial;
    color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

and here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eR9SP/21/

In the code-snippet provided, when I hover over the track it turns blue. When I hover over the thumb, the track turns blue and the thumb turns dark gray.

I am hoping to invert this behavior. I would like to thumb to turn dark gray when the track is highlighted and I would like the track to remain white when the thumb is hovered. Is that possible with CSS or JavaScript?

My reasoning is:

- When the mouse is hovering over the track -- clicking will perform an action which moves the thumb. So, I think the thumb should change color when hovering the track because it is the thumb which will move.
- When hovering your mouse over the thumb -- changing the color of the track doesn't make sense. The thumb is the active element.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to not have the track color change.

I don't know how you would make the thumb's color change when hovering only over the track. I tried adding JQuery to your fiddle example, but it didn't recognize `.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track` as a valid thing to put a hover event on, I guess because it's not a standard.